# React/Redux: Can't access store variable as props from another component after action dispatched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm fairly new to redux, so I might be doing something silly here.

I have a LoginComponent that should set a variable called `loggedIn` in the global store set to `true` indicating the user is logged in. The navigation bar then should be able to then display buttons (login/register or logout) depending on whether that variable is true or not.

I have a LoginComponent that looks like this:

```
class LoginComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //... local state stuff for render()
    }

    login() {
        let self = this;
        axios.post('/user/login', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }).then(function (response) {
            self.setState({errorMessage: ''});
            self.props.setLoggedIn(true); //Here is the action that should be dispatching to change the variable. 
            self.props.history.push('/'); 
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
              //A simple login form with username/password.
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { loggedIn } = state;
    return { loggedIn };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ setLoggedIn }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginComponent);
```

Then I have the action in `UserActions.js`:

```
export function setLoggedIn(loggedIn) {
    const action = {
        type: 'SET_LOGGED_IN',
        loggedIn
    };
    return action;
}
```

Followed by the reducer in `UserReducer.js`:

```
export default ((state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_LOGGED_IN':
            let { loggedIn } = action;
            return loggedIn;
        default:
            return state;
    }
});
```

And somehow this should I should be able to access this in my `NavBarComponent` via `this.props`:

```
class NavBarComponent extends Component {
    test() {
        console.log(this.props);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div><button className="btn btn-default btn-header" onClick={() => {this.test()}}>Check</button></div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { loggedIn } = state;
    return { loggedIn };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(NavBarComponent);
```

However, in my console, upon calling the `test()` function in my NavBarComponent I see:

`Object {history: Object, loggedIn: undefined, dispatch: function}`

So, the question is, why is loggedIn undefined instead of true or false?

**Edit**

This is how my store/provider looks like in index.js:

```
let store = createStore(AppReducer);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <div>
            <Router path="/" history={browserHistory}>
                <div>
                    <NavBarComponent history={browserHistory}/>
                    <Route path="/login" component={LoginComponent} />
                    <Route path="/register" component={RegisterComponent} />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={AppComponent}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        </div>
    </Provider>, document.getElementById('root')
);
```

And my AppReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import UserReducer from '../User/UserReducer'

export default combineReducers({
    UserReducer
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is in `UserReducer.js`

```
export default ((state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_LOGGED_IN':
            let { loggedIn } = action;
            return loggedIn;
        default:
            return state;
    }
});
```

Without seeing how the store is created, my guess is this should look more like

```
export default ((state = {}, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SET_LOGGED_IN':
            let { loggedIn } = action;
            // assuming you have the spread operator available - if not, use Object.assign({}, state, { loggedIn })
            return { ...state, loggedIn };
        default:
            return state;
    }
});
```

---

### Explanation

Firstly, the initial state.  Yours defaults `state` to `[]` which is an empty array, but you use it like an object, so I switched it to `{}`, an empty object.

Secondly, the reducer function should return immutable changes to the state, but must still return the whole state. So your `SET_LOGGED_IN` handler was changing the state to be a single boolean value, rather than just changing the `loggedIn` value

```
let { loggedIn } = action;
return loggedIn;
```

The [spread operator or `Object.assign`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingObjectSpreadOperator.html) can be used to copy the existing state, but replace the `loggedIn` value

```
let { loggedIn } = action;
// assuming you have the spread operator available - if not, use Object.assign({}, state, { loggedIn })
return { ...state, loggedIn };
```

---

### Tips

A good tool to track these sorts of issues down is the [redux devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools).  You can see what actions are dispatched and how the state was affected.

Alternatively, a simple trick is to place `console.log(state)' in the`mapStateToProps` function to see what you have to work with

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log(state)
    const { loggedIn } = state;
    return { loggedIn };
}
```

---

### Edit after comments

If you're seeing the state as

```
{ 
    /* other stuff */ 
    UserReducer: {
        loggedIn: true 
    } 
    /* maybe more stuff */ 
}
```

then I assume you are using [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html) when you create the store.  This is the normal behaviour, e.g.

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({ SomeReducer, UserReducer, OtherReducer })
```

The normal behaviour for `combineReducers` is to nest each slice of state in with the key of the reducer map that was combined.

If this is the case, then you should be using the full path to access the state on your components

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        loggedIn: state.UserReducer.loggedIn 
    };
}
```

If you want to change the key to better represent your domain, you can just use a different key when combining

```
const store = createStore(combineReducers({ someReducer, user: UserReducer, otherReducer })

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { 
        loggedIn: state.user.loggedIn 
    };
}
```

Comment: So I made the changes you specified and my understanding is this: state is an object that contains a bunch of variables and every time I modify the state, I need to specify which part of the state I'm modifying and keep the rest of the state using the spread operator.

Comment: I also noticed when I log out the mapStateToProps `state` variable, I see a `UserReducer` object with a variable called `loggedIn` set to `true`... is that what I'm supposed to see?

Comment: For the re-rendering of the buttons part not working, I had to change my mapStateToProps to:
`function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { loggedIn } = state.UserReducer;
    return { loggedIn };
}` which seemed to work although I'm still curious if that's something that makes sense.

Comment: This is why I had "Without seeing how the store is created" in my answer. 
 I've updated my answer for the new information.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_LOGGED_IN':
        let { loggedIn } = action;
        return loggedIn; // this will make your state true
    default:
        return state;
}
```

try returning action i.e `{ loggedIn: true }`;

and you can access it from here

```
    function mapStateToProps(state) {
      const { loggedIn } = state;
      return { loggedIn };
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you mean `return { loggedIn : true }`, I tried that, and it seems to produce similar results.